# AngularJS: ng-repeat add some text with first element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat and would like to ask if we can add some extra text with first item?

```
 var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

 <div ng-repeat="item in items">
     {{item}}
 </div>
```

What i want is, it return me result like:

```
1 Hello
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take advantage of the angular `$index` variable, that gives you the index of the item in the collection:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
     {{item}} <span ng-if="$index === 0">Hello</span>
</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
     {{item}} <span ng-if="$first">Hello</span>
</div>
```

See **[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)**

You have the following special values:

- $first
- $middle
- $last
- $even
- $odd

Answer (score 1):

Can use a variety of special properties added to the child scope in `ng-repeat` and for this it includes `$first` along with `$index, $last, $middle, $even, $odd`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
     {{item}} {{ $first ? 'I am first item' :''}}
 </div>
```